# Is there a way to test SocketMobile integration without actual scanner?

Tags: socketscan, socketmobile

I have Android and iOS React Native app that requires user to scan barcodes. I am now working on integration with SocketMobile scanner.

Is there a way to test integration without actual scanner device? Maybe there's some kind of emulator?

Answer (score 1):

Using the SDK you can enable a "SoftScan" device, which uses the built-in camera. The SoftScan device behaves just like a physical device and can be configured using the same APIs.

### Enabling SoftScan

After ScanAPI is initialized; most likely inside `ScanApiHelperNotification.onScanApiInitializeComplete()`

```
mScanApiHelper.postSetSoftScanStatus(kSktScanEnableSoftScan, callback)
```

Once SoftScan is enabled, you will immediately receive a device arrival notification - in the same way you receive a device arrival notification when a physical device is connected via Bluetooth.

The SoftScan device does not support *all* the properties of a physical device and will return an unsupported error if you try to get/set one of the properties it does not support.

SoftScan uses the [Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&hl=en) app, so make sure it is installed on your device